# WPF "object" browser similar to Windows explorer?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, explorer

I'm writing a server management application. I want to show a and a "grid" or whatever you want to call it, with an icon for each server. Kind of like how Explorer has an icon with text for each file/folder. The reason this needs to be a "grid" layout is that each server is shown on the grid with a small screenshot of the server, plus the server name below said screenshot. Similar to browsing albums in iTunes (icon of the album, name underneath).

To goal is to have it so a user will either be able to right-click a server and get a menu with some options, or select the server and a new "manage" tab will appear on my application's Ribbon.

Comment: So what is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you want with WPF.

For a nice article on replicating the Windows Vista/7 View menu, check out [this article by Dr. WPF.](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/28/itemscontrol-r-is-for-rob-has-a-customer/)

[image]